# Freaky Deaky File

Tags: c, function, file-io

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void get_file(void);
float Max_Horizontal(int, int);
float Max_Verticle(int, int);
float Time(int,int);

int main(void)
{

    get_file();

    return (0);
}

void get_file(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int A[8][2];
    char buf[1000];

    FILE*Fpointin =fopen("trajin.txt","r");
    FILE*Fpointout =fopen("trajout.txt","w");

    if (Fpointin == NULL)
        {
            printf ("File does not exist.\n");
        }
    else
        {
            fgets(buf,1000, Fpointin);
        }

    while ((fscanf(Fpointin,"%d %d",&A[i][0],&A[i][1])==2))
        {
            {i++;}
            fprintf(Fpointout, "%.2f\t %.2f\t %.2f\t %.2f\t %.2f \n", A[i][0],A[i][1], Max_Horizontal(A[i][0],A[i][1]), Max_Verticle(A[i][0],A[i][1]), Time(A[i][0],A[i][1]));
        }
        fclose(Fpointin);
        fclose(Fpointout);
}

float Max_Horizontal(iInTrajectoryAngle,fInVelocity)
{
    double fMaxRange = 0;

    fMaxRange = ((pow(fInVelocity,2)*sin((((iInTrajectoryAngle*M_PI)/180)* 2)))/9.81);

    return(fMaxRange);
}

float Max_Verticle(iInTrajectoryAngle,fInVelocity)
{
    double fMaxHeight = 0;

    fMaxHeight =  (pow(fInVelocity,2) * pow(sin(((iInTrajectoryAngle*M_PI)/180)),2) / (2*9.81));

    return (fMaxHeight);
}

float Time(iInTrajectoryAngle, fInVelocity)
{
    double fFlightTime = 0;

    fFlightTime = ((2 * fInVelocity * sin(((iInTrajectoryAngle*M_PI)/180))/9.81 ));

    return (fFlightTime);
}
```

Hi all, I've pretty much got this short program all done for one of those automated online class things but the output file is all weird and I can't seem to figure out why. Of course the website isn't much of a help because it can't really point out how to help fix my errors.The input file is a simple .txt file as shown below

Initial angle (degrees)     initial velocity (meter per second)
10              100
20              120
30              130
40              140
50              150
60              160
70              170
80              180

Comment: We can't be of much help either if you don't include your errors or tell us what is happening instead of the desired result. Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: the worst part is that it isn't throwing any specific errors so it much be a logic error. the output file is spitting out random answers of varying sizes and one that is a never ending line of zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Had to change

```
fprintf(Fpointout, "%f\t %f\t\t %.2f\t %.2f\t %.2f\n", A[i][0],A[i][1], Max_Horizontal(A[i][0],A[i][1]), Max_Verticle(A[i][0],A[i][1]), Time(A[i][0],A[i][1]));
```

to

```
fprintf(Fpointout, "%d\t %d\t\t %.2f\t %.2f\t %.2f\n", A[i][0],A[i][1], Max_Horizontal(A[i][0],A[i][1]), Max_Verticle(A[i][0],A[i][1]), Time(A[i][0],A[i][1]));
```

note the change of types.